# Mysql 5.7.21 inconsistent only_full_group_by behavior with EF6 and Mysql Connector 6.9.9

Tags: mysql

We just upgraded our Mysql db from 5.6 to 5.7.21.
Then all the sql statements that are written against sql_mode:only_full_group_by gave error. That's the normal behavior of Mysql 5.7.21 because sql_mode parameter in my.ini was set to "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY".
Then we set this parameter to empty string ("") in my.ini and restarted server again. Everything seemed normal for just a 1 or 2 minutes , then the same queries began to give only_full_group_by error again.
We are still trying to find a solution without touching our codebase bu we couldn't yet.

You can see a live exmaple in this link
Please refreseh the page 10 times or more to get the page work.

http://www.karoltekstil.com.tr/atlet-ust-giyim/k/10-42?page=1

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a question?

Comment: i will give you a trade secret.. invalid written queries with GROUP BY which are not ANSI proof in MySQL can and will cause **invalid** results..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i know that secret . The problem is this is not the only application and we dont have time to rewrite all queries

Comment: @spencer7593 The question is "How can mysql give only_full_group_by error even its not set in my.ini?"

Answer (score 0):

Each MySQL session (database connection) has its own setting for `sql_mode`.

When a new session is started (a new connection is made to the database), the `sql_mode` *session* variable inherits the setting of the *global* `sql_mode` setting.

While a session is running, it can change the setting of its own `sql_mode`, for example by issuing a statement like this:

```
SET @@session.sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' ;
```

The new value of `sql_mode` remains in effect for that session, until it is changed again, or until the session ends.

A user with sufficient privilege can also change the *global* setting of `sql_mode`, with a statement like this for example:

```
SET @@global.sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' ;
```

Any change made the global setting only affects new sessions (connections started after the change is applied.) Changes to the global setting don't influence sessions that are already started. The existing sessions already have their "copy" of `sql_mode` that was  inherited when the connection was started.

Note that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` can be explicit in `sql_mode`, or it can be included implicitly in a combination setting. For example, `sql_mode='ANSI'` includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

---

MySQL startup has a variety of locations that it reads configuration information from, whether that's `my.ini`, `my.cnf`, or options provided on the command line of the startup.

Next steps in debugging this is to determine if `sql_mode` is being set properly when the database starts, and then determine if there are statements being executed in individual sessions that change the setting of sql_mode.

Is the application churning database connections, starting and ending discrete sessions?

Or is the application using a connection pool, persistent connections that are borrowed and returned from the pool?

Comment: thanks for the detailed response , i'm sure that sql_mode is set correctly in my ini because when we issue show variables , sql_mode is shown blank. Also we dont issue any initial command before a new connection and "init_connect" variable is also blank. Our applications are using connection pool by default . We dont override it in connectionstring.

Comment: Then I suspect that it's either the connection pool configuration, or some code that borrows connections from the pool... one of those is issuing a statement that changes the sql_mode, and doesn't change it back.  Most connection pools have a "test on borrow" configuration, makes the pool run a statement on the connection to test that it's valid, before it passes it to the caller. As a fix, we could modify the pool configuration to add a `SET @@session.sql_mode=''...` statement to the "test on borrow" config, so the session `sql_mode` is reset whenever a process gets a session from the pool.

Comment: I dont know how to modify "test on borrow" config , but i disabled connection pooling with  connection string and everything seems normal for the last 15 minutes. I'll write here if any error occurs again

Comment: We would expect disabling the connection pool would fix the problem if something in the code is changing session `sql_mode`, now that those sessions aren't getting reused, a subsequent requests are getting new connections, not old connections that are saddled with whatever state a previous borrower left it in.